# How do I turn on function name completion?

Tags: r, code-golf

In golfing, one tries to complete a puzzle in as few characters as possible, generally using the base language only.  One [trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4024/tips-for-golfing-in-r) for golfing in R is to use partial completion so that e.g. `rle(...)$length` can be shortened to `rle(...)$l`.  How does one turn on function name completion in R, preferably in as few characters as possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
`?` <- function(object){
    object <- deparse(substitute(object))
    splt <- strsplit(object,"(",fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
    object <- splt[1]
    if(length(splt)>1)
        func <- paste("(",splt[2],collapse="")
    else
        func <- ""
    envs <- sapply(search(),as.environment)
    objs <- do.call("c",lapply(envs,function(x) ls(envir=x,all.names=TRUE)))
    matches <- objs[grep(object,objs)]
    objectMatch <- matches[which.min(nchar(matches))][1]
    res <- eval(parse(text=paste(objectMatch,func,collapse="")), envir = parent.frame())
    res
}
```

This overloads the help operator to provide the shortest object matching the regular expression provided. For example:

```
> ?as.ch
function (x, ...)  .Primitive("as.character")
> a<-1
> ?as.ch(a)
[1] "1"
```

Comment: Great, now all that's needed is to move this into core R so that we can code-golf without having to define the function `?` as above. Shouldn't be hard since golfing is so much more important than help ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by @Ian, here is a golf version of @Ian's answer.
The concept is similar but use some R-ish hack (i.e., call tree manipulation)

```
`?`<-function(o)with(x<-as.list(substitute(o)),do.call(apropos(paste("^",deparse(x[[1]]),sep=""))[1],x[-1]))
```

try:

```
> ?me(1:5)
[1] 3
> a<-1;?as.ch(a)
[1] "1"
>
```

for golf, `R` needs a shortcut of `function`.